# Generate a sparse row stochastic matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, stochastic

I'm trying to generate a sparse stochastic matrix with Matlab but currently running into problems. Here is where I'm currently at.

```
N=10
i = round(rand(1,N)*10)+1 
j = round(rand(1,N)*10)+1

S1 = sparse (i,j,1,N,N);
S = full(S1)

rowsum = sum(S,2); 
S = bsxfun(@rdivide, S, rowsum);
```

Now this last line is where it fails. There are some zero rows in the sparse matrix.

So my question is how can I normalize each row yet preserve the zero rows?

Comment: The line `S1 = sparse (i,j,1,N,N);` causes errors as well. max(i) and max(j) is 11 in some cases, which exceeds the size of NxN.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple model i would use:

```
%logical matrix, a web page links to 20% of the other websites on average. This is a strange model, but I don't have a better idear:
doeslink=rand(N)<.2.*1-eye(N)
%generate random link weights
S=rand(N).*doeslink
%avoid nans
rowsum(rowsum==0)=1
%normalise
S = bsxfun(@rdivide, S, rowsum);
```

Comment: Thank you. I would vote up your answer but I'm too new.

Comment: You can always [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question.